# Websockify "ignoring socket not ready" Firefox 15

Tags: firefox, websocket, vnc

I'm using [Websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) to connect to a VNC Server (TightVNC) via [noVNC](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC). This worked great with Firefox 14.0.1, Chrome 21 and even IE 10. Now I upgraded to Firefox 15 and the problems start:

This is a sample output from websockify:

```
>websockify.exe 6080 localhost:5900 -v
WARNING: no 'resource' module, daemonizing support disabled
WebSocket server settings:
  - Listen on :6080
  - Flash security policy server
  - No SSL/TLS support (no cert file)
  - proxying from :6080 to localhost:5900

#Connection with Chrome

  1: 79.194.220.16: Plain non-SSL (ws://) WebSocket connection
  1: 79.194.220.16: Version hybi-13, base64: 'True'
  1: connecting to: localhost:5900

Traffic Legend:
    }  - Client receive
    }. - Client receive partial
    {  - Target receive

    >  - Target send
    >. - Target send partial
    <  - Client send
    <. - Client send partial

{<}>{<}>{<}>{<}>{<}>{{<<}>}>{}><}>}>}>}>  1: localhost:5900: Target closed
  1: 79.194.220.16: Client closed, reason: None - None

#Chrome disconnected, Firefox tries to connect

  2: 79.194.220.16: ignoring socket not ready
  3: 79.194.220.16: Plain non-SSL (ws://) WebSocket connection
  3: 79.194.220.16: Version hybi-13, base64: 'True'
  3: connecting to: localhost:5900

Traffic Legend:
    }  - Client receive
    }. - Client receive partial
    {  - Target receive

    >  - Target send
    >. - Target send partial
    <  - Client send
    <. - Client send partial

{<
```

After the last line websockify hangs, accepting no other connection. Here is the console Ouput from Firefox:

```
New state 'loaded', was 'disconnected'. Msg: noVNC ready: native WebSockets, canvas rendering

util.js (Zeile 110)

New state 'connect', was 'loaded'.

util.js (Zeile 110)

WebSocket on-error event

util.js (Zeile 110)

New state 'failed', was 'connect'. Msg: Connect timeout


case 'error': Util.Error = function (msg) { console.error(msg); };

util.js (Zeile 111)

Firefox kann keine Verbindung zu dem Server unter ws://ec2-176-34-194-149.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:6080/websockify aufbauen.


websocket = new WebSocket(uri, 'base64');

websock.js (Zeile 275)

WebSocket on-close event

util.js (Zeile 110)

Received onclose while disconnected (code: 1006)


case 'error': Util.Error = function (msg) { console.error(msg); };

util.js (Zeile 111)

New state 'disconnected', was 'failed'.
```

As said, this worked perfectly in FF 14.0.1 and still works in Chrome 21 and IE 10.

Any idea why Firefox chrashes websockify? Is this a bug in Firefox Websocket code or a bug in Websockify?

Comment: It's a good chance that's it a Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've replied to your Mozilla bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789018

In summary, it's a Windows/python problem combined with a mis-feature in firefox 15 (speculative connect).

As a temporary solution you can increase the connect timeout in noVNC.

Comment: Jep, that was it. Increasing the timeout to 10sec helped.